# Out of memory exception in c# for infinite loop

Tags: c#, .net, out-of-memory

Just trying to understand the out of memory exception in dot net.

If I create a infinite while loop and in the loop I create a new object and that object writes something to a file.

Will this application run out of memory? Will this cause out of memory exception?

Comment: Yes. Writing to file is not relevant here though..

Comment: It depends on what is the size of the object and mostly GC would collect the object. So just doing something in a while loop and writing to file won't result in Out of memory exception.

Answer (score 1):

An OutOfMemoryException is thrown whenever the application tries and fails to allocate memory to perform an operation. According to [Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.outofmemoryexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), the following operations can potentially throw an OutOfMemoryException:

- Boxing (i.e., wrapping a value type in an Object)
- Creating an array
- Creating an object

If you try to create an infinite number of objects, then it's pretty reasonable to assume that you're going to run out of memory sooner or later.

(**Note:** don't forget about the [garbage collector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Depending on the lifetimes of the objects being created, it will delete some of them if it determines they're no longer in use.)